# Simplify with assumption of unknown function

Tags: evaluation, simplifying-expressions, assumptions

I have an unknown multivariate function entry[x,y,z], which is positive. Then how to get FALSE and entry[1,2,3] in the following evaluations?

```
FullSimplify[entry[1, 2, 3] < 0, entry[_, _, _] > 0]
FullSimplify[Sqrt[entry[1, 2, 3]^2], entry[_, _, _] > 0]
```

Comment: Related: [(6182)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/6182/121)

Comment: Very closely related, probably a duplicate: [Unknown function with arbitrary arguments assumption](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/67343/245)

Comment: The accepted answer to the question I linked earlier also works for this case. So I would say it's a duplicate. You just have to do your simplifications wrapped by `AssumingAll[entry[__]>0, ...]`

Comment: @Jens Thanks! Maybe I agree this is a duplicate. I am such a novice in Mathematica that I cannot immediately comprehand the commands in that "AssumingAll" function. So I gave my own poor solution beneath. I guess that "AssumingAll" is more advanced in functionality. It will be so nice of you to say something about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here comes a simple solution, perhaps. The two cases characterize the usage well.

```
expr = Sqrt[f[y[qq], z]^2] + Sqrt[DD[2, 3, 4]^2] + (f[1, 2] > 0);

FullSimplify[expr, Thread[Cases[expr, x_[___] /; ! ValueQ[x], Infinity] > 0]]
FullSimplify[expr, Thread[Cases[expr, f[___] /; ! ValueQ[f], Infinity] > 0]]

Out[94]= True + DD[2, 3, 4] + f[y[qq], z]
Out[95]= True + Sqrt[DD[2, 3, 4]^2] + f[y[qq], z]
```

Comment: The output doesn't seem to make mathematical sense because addition of logical values isn't defined.

Comment: Yes. I just want to show the possible usage.

Answer (score 1):

This might be what you want:

```
myfullsimplify[expr_, assum_] := Module[
  {pat, tmp, seq},
  pat = FirstCase[Level[assum, Infinity], p[_]] /. p[x_] -> x;
  tmp = FirstCase[Level[expr, Infinity], pat];
  seq = {expr, assum} /. {pat -> #, p[_] -> #};
  FullSimplify @@ seq /. # -> tmp
]
```

It's used as follows:

```
myfullsimplify[entry[1, 2, 3] < 0, p[entry[_, _, _]] > 0]
myfullsimplify[Sqrt[entry[1, 2, 3]^2], p[entry[_, _, _]] > 0]
```

You'd have to wrap your pattern with `p[...]` though.